# WM_SETTEXT taking too long time for multiline editbox with ES_RIGHT style

Tags: c++, winapi

I send about one MB Unicode text to a multiline TEXTBOX using WM_SETTEXT. it takes 30 seconds or more to complete. But pasting the same 1MB from clipboard is very fast. What is the problem? Any idea or link appreciated.
I use VS2017 community for all my code.

Edit: I deleted previous edits to clarify the problem.
Here is a minimal, complete, verifiable code code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

struct VIEWTEMPLATE : public DLGTEMPLATE {
    unsigned __int16 nMenu;
    unsigned __int16 nClass;
    unsigned __int16 nTitle;
    unsigned __int16 nPointSize;
    wchar_t wszFaceName[10];
};

WNDPROC g_lpfnOriginalWndProc;
HINSTANCE g_hInstance;

static void uPasteFromClipBoard(HWND hwndControl)
{
    HWND wndParent = GetParent(hwndControl);
    if (!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT)) return;
    if (!OpenClipboard(hwndControl)) return;
    const wchar_t * lpwszText = nullptr;
    HGLOBAL hgClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
    if (hgClipboardData)
    {
        lpwszText = (const wchar_t *)GlobalLock(hgClipboardData);
    }
    if (!lpwszText)
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return;
    }
    SendMessageW(hwndControl, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)lpwszText);
    GlobalUnlock(hgClipboardData);
    CloseClipboard();
}

static LRESULT uCtrlProc(HWND hwndControl, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_PASTE: uPasteFromClipBoard(hwndControl); return 1;
    default: break;
    }
    return CallWindowProc(g_lpfnOriginalWndProc, hwndControl, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

static int uInitDialog(HWND hwndDlg)
{
    //create a multiline edit control
    int iStyle1 = ES_RIGHT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL;
    //I discovered that removing ES_RIGHT solves the problem
    int iStyle2 = WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL;
    int cpLeft = 10;
    int cpTop = 10;
    int cpWidth = 500;
    int cpHeight = 200;
    HWND hwndEdit = CreateWindowExW(
        0, L"EDIT", L"Paste here", iStyle1 | iStyle2,
        cpLeft, cpTop, cpWidth, cpHeight,
        hwndDlg, nullptr, g_hInstance, nullptr
    );
    if (!hwndEdit)
        return false;
    ShowWindow(hwndEdit, SW_SHOW);
    g_lpfnOriginalWndProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtrW(hwndEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC);
    SetWindowLongPtrW(hwndEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC, (ULONG_PTR)uCtrlProc);
    return true;
}

static INT_PTR uDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: return uInitDialog(hwndDlg);
    default: return 0L;
    }
};

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    //create a dialog template. resource dialogs have no problem
    VIEWTEMPLATE *dt;
    dt = (VIEWTEMPLATE *)malloc(sizeof(VIEWTEMPLATE));
    if (!dt) return 0;
    memset(dt, 0, sizeof(*dt));
    dt->style =
        DS_SETFONT | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE |
        DS_MODALFRAME | DS_3DLOOK | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |
        WS_BORDER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
    dt->dwExtendedStyle = WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    dt->cdit = 0;
    dt->x = 0;
    dt->y = 0;
    dt->cx = 520;
    dt->cy = 220;
    dt->nPointSize = 10;
    LRESULT iResult = DialogBoxIndirectParamW(
        nullptr,
        dt,
        nullptr,
        uDlgProc,
        0
    );
    free(dt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I send about one MB` -- Please give more details on what is meant by "send".

Comment: I think he's literally invoking `SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, msg)` where `msg` is a string of 1MB in length.  That's probably entirely too much.

Comment: @selbie I doubt that sending one set text message with a large amount of text is slow.

Comment: Please show [mcve]

Comment: I've tried a repro with a MB string using SendMessage and SetDlgItemText. Both are fast.

Comment: If it takes 30sec to complete, it should be easy to hit the Pause button of the debugger and see where the program is processing stuff. Is it really in the `WM_SETTEXT` handler, or is some callback called that does extra work? Hit Pause repeatedly (as a poor man's profiler, so to say).

Comment: What does [IsWindowUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowunicode) return for the `v1->hWnd` handle? Is the target a window you control (i.e. a window you created)? Is this a standard edit control, or is it subclassed in any way?

Comment: @Hefferman: I added a minimal and complete sample project created by VS2017

Comment: @j6t: I added a sample project link in EDIT3

Comment: @IInspectable: I added a minimal, complete project link in EDIT3

Comment: Post a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Comment: Links to off-site code are not a [mcve]. Off-site content may not be available in the future, which means your question will have no value here. All relevant content must be here. Please spend some time reading [mcve] as well as [ask] to learn how this site works, and then come back and [edit] your post to provide that MCVE here, in the question itself.

Comment: @Ken White: Please see my edit

Comment: @selbie: you didn't check edit box with ES_CENTER or ES_RIGHT style. both are extremely slow

Answer (score 0):

Dialog templates have a very specific format and require `DWORD` alignment. Your implementation is incorrect and is likely causing undefined behavior.

An easier solution is to use the resource editor to create a dialog, and simply call `DialogBox(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, DialogProc)`. This method is much easier, more versatile, and safer.

By default, edit control has a 32K limit. This limit is not changed in above example, so it's unclear how you insert 1 MB.

Edit control will handle `WM_PASTE` message automatically, as long as it has focus. If edit control does not have focus, then `WM_PASTE` is sent to the dialog, you can simply pass `WM_PASTE` to the edit control.

`SetWindowLongPtr` is outdated method for subclassing controls. Use `SetWindowSubclass` instead.

Try the example below. I used the dialog template method again, but using resource editor is strongly recommended. This code should be compiled in Unicode.

```
//#define UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

//adding library (Visual Studio specific)
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

#define ID_EDIT 200

LRESULT CALLBACK EditProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp,
    UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR)
{
    switch(msg) 
    {
    case WM_PASTE: 
    {
        if(!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT)) break;
        if(!OpenClipboard(hwnd)) break;
        HANDLE hdata = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
        const wchar_t *lpwszText = (const wchar_t*)GlobalLock(hdata);
        SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)lpwszText);
        GlobalUnlock(hdata);
        CloseClipboard();
        return FALSE;
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, EditProc, 0);
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: 
    {
        HWND hedit = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_EDIT);

        //increase the text limit
        SendMessage(hedit, EM_LIMITTEXT, 0x7FFF'FFFF, 0);

        //subclass edit control if necessary
        SetWindowSubclass(hedit, EditProc, 0, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wparam))
        {
        case IDOK: EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
        case IDCANCEL: EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
        }
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
};

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
{
    HGLOBAL hgbl = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT, 2048);
    if(!hgbl)
        return -1;

    const wchar_t *buf;
    int buflen;
    DLGITEMTEMPLATE *item;

    LPWORD ptr = (LPWORD)GlobalLock(hgbl);

    DLGTEMPLATE *dlgtemplate = (DLGTEMPLATE*)ptr;
    dlgtemplate->style = WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_CAPTION;
    dlgtemplate->cdit = 1; /* Number of controls */
    dlgtemplate->x = 10;
    dlgtemplate->y = 10;
    dlgtemplate->cx = 200;
    dlgtemplate->cy = 200;
    ptr = (LPWORD)(dlgtemplate + 1);

    //no menu
    *ptr++ = 0;

    //predefined dialog box class (by default)
    *ptr++ = 0;

    //Title
    buf = L"Dialog title";
    buflen = wcslen(buf);
    memcpy(ptr, buf, buflen * sizeof(wchar_t));
    ptr += buflen + (buflen % 2);

    ptr++;

    //-----------------------
    // Define a edit control.
    //-----------------------
    item = (DLGITEMTEMPLATE*)ptr;
    item->x = 10;
    item->y = 10;
    item->cx = 180;
    item->cy = 180;
    item->id = ID_EDIT;
    item->style = WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
        ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_VSCROLL;
    ptr = (LPWORD)(item + 1);

    //edit class
    *ptr++ = 0xFFFF;
    *ptr++ = 0x0081;

    //edit window text not set...

    ptr++;

    GlobalUnlock(hgbl);
    LRESULT ret = DialogBoxIndirect(hInstance, dlgtemplate, NULL, DlgProc);
    GlobalFree(hgbl);
    return ret; 
}
```

Comment: Tanks for your very good tips and advises. I create an empty dialog template and pot all controls on it dynamically. I added style ES_RIGHT to your code and ran it. The problem remains. there is no problem with ES_LEFT or without ES_RIGHT. I think the key problem is in ES_RIGHT style. It slows down WM_SETTEXT considerably even if no all chars in text are ltr

Comment: @MohamadrezaAbdolahzadeh Both your code and Barmak Shemirani's I have tested. About 1 second with ES_RIGHT style. I can't reproduce your issue that "takes 30 seconds or more to complete".